# Is it possible to specify both JSON and XML ResponseFormat for a webservice method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am converting an application from Java to .NET and I am working on the webservice part right now.

I have these lines in a java webservice interface:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/selelement/list")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response getSelElementsByAppId(@QueryParam("appId") int appId);
```

And I am converting them to this in a .NET ASMX file:

```
  [WebMethod]
  [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
  public HttpResponse getSelElementsByAppId(@QueryParam("appId") int appId) { //code here }
```

Problem being is that the java interface takes in JSON and XML in the `@Produces` tag. Is there a way for me to specify both ResponseFormats in .NET file?

If that's not possible, what's the next best way to convert this java webservice method over to .NET?

Web config for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <add name="HttpGet"/>
                <add name="HttpPost"/>
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```